# mod_proxy_json or mod_proxy_hal+json

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, mod-proxy-html

[`mod_proxy_html`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) rewrites links in HTML pages.
I would like to accomplish the same for JSON responses with HAL controls (links).
Is anyone aware of such a module?

Comment: I am not aware of such a module, but then again there are literally thousands of modules out there, though mostly for outdated versions of the apache http server. I want to point you to the substitution module, though. It allows to define commands and is typically used to replace references or keywords in a given response. Not a trivial task to implement, but you have the full power of scripting at your finger tips.

Comment: Thank u @arkascha. I'll have a look into it.